# Pushing forward-lookup zones to VPN clients' dnsmasq configuration

Tags: 12.04, openvpn, dnsmasq

Ubuntu 12.04 uses a nice little automagic dnsmasq configuration for handling name resolution across DNS connections so that name resolution happens properly.

When I connect to my OpenVPN server at work (for which I am the administrator) the client recognizes the reverse lookup networks properly and puts lines for those into the dnsmasq config, but not the forward networks:

```
/var/run/nm-dns-dnsmasq.conf:
server=/10.in-addr.arpa/192.168.0.5
server=/0.168.192.in-addr.arpa/192.168.0.5
server=192.168.1.3
```

The contents should be:

```
server=/workdomain.ca/192.168.0.5
server=/10.in-addr.arpa/192.168.0.5
server=/0.168.192.in-addr.arpa/192.168.0.5
server=192.168.1.3
```

What do I need to change on my OpenVPN server (pfsense) to push one or more search domains to the VPN client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, my client doesn't recognize the domains correctly and just uses the one DNS server my VPN server pushses rather than only using my VPN DNS for VPN domains.  To answer your question though, look into using push "dhcp-option DOMAIN example.com"

Comment: This solves the immediate problem, though I'm still left with the question of how to add more than one domain.